# np.linspace vs range in Bokeh

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a coding newcomer and I'm trying to work with Bokeh. Newcomer to StackOverflow too, so please tell me if I did something wrong here.

I'm playing with [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html) from Bokeh website and I ran into a problem. When the x values are set, as in the example, using np.linspace, I'm able to use the interact and play with the update function. But, if I change x to a list, using range(), then I get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list. As I understand it, the problem lies in "x + phi", since x is a list and phi is a float.

I get that it's not possible to concatenate a list with a float, but why is it only when I use a numpy.ndarray that Python understands that I want to modify the function that controls the y values?

Here is the code (I'm using Jupyter Notebook):

```
x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y = np.sin(x)
p = figure(title="example", plot_height=300, plot_width=600, y_range=(-5,5))
r = p.line(x, y)

def update(f, w=1, A=1, phi=0):
    if   f == "sin": func = np.sin
    elif f == "cos": func = np.cos
    elif f == "tan": func = np.tan
    r.data_source.data["y"] = A * func(w * x + phi)
    push_notebook()

show(p, notebook_handle=True)
interact(update, f=["sin", "cos", "tan"], w=(0,100), A=(1,5), phi=(0,20, 0.1))
```

Comment: Lists and ndarrays assign completely different meanings to the `+` operator. They are extremely different types, and you should never assume one will behave like the other.

Comment: You probably can use `x=np.arange(0,10,.01)`, which has `range` like parameters, but produces a `numpy` array.

Comment: The `+` operator performs addition on numpy arrays, but concatenation on lists. `np.array([1]) + np.array([1]) == np.array([2])`, but `[1] + [1] == [1, 1]`. As @hpaulj said, use `np.arange` in place of `range` to get a numpy array output rather than a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please compare your numpy documentation with the documentation of lists: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html

You can also play with the following code:

```
from numpy import linspace

a = linspace(2, 3, num=5)
b = range(5)

print(type(a), a)
print(type(b), b)
print()
print("array + array:", a + a)
print("list + list:", b + b)
print(a + 3.14159)
print(b + 2.718) # will fail as in your example, because it is a list
```

My advise is to not mix lists and arrays if there is no other good reason to do so. I personally often cast function arguments to arrays if necessary:

```
def f(an_array):
    an_array = numpy.array(an_array)
    # continue knowing that it is an array now,
    # being aware that I make a copy of an_array at this point
```